# What can we say about the set of asymptotic equivalence classes of sequences?

Tags: asymptotics

Say that
$$A := \{f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}\}/\sim$$
where $f \sim g$ if $f$ and $g$ are asymptotically equivalent.  That is, let $A$ be the set of asymptotic equivalence classes of real functions.

What can be said about $A$?  For instance:

- Does the set $A$ have an interesting topology?  Metric?  Poset structure?
- Is there any kind of canonical representative of a given equivalence class?  (I assume such a statement would require some extra conditions, since there are obviously many classes of things that grow ridiculously fast.)
- Does the set $A$ have a name?  Is it studied anywhere?

Comment: This is related to the [Big $O$ notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean by asymptotically equivalent, there's a natural order given by $f \le g$ iff $f = O(g)$. See [fast-growing hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy) and [Hardy hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy_hierarchy) for interesting examples of ordinals embedded into this order.